# Set image draggable dynamically

Tags: javascript, image, draggable

I'm having problems setting my image to be draggable.
This code doesn't seem to work:

```
var thumb = document.createElement("img");
thumb.setAttribute('draggable', "true");
```

I create and append my image to DOM like this: 
 var thumb = document.createElement("img");

```
        thumb.setAttribute('draggable', "true");
        thumb.setAttribute('alt', label);
        thumb.setAttribute('id', "dhmvseries_" + label);
        thumb.setAttribute("dhmvseriesuuid",label);

        thumb.ondragstart =  thumbDragStart;
        thumb.ondragend = thumbDragEnd;
        thumb.onmouseover = displayThumbInfo;
        thumb.onmouseout = hideThumbInfo;

var thinner = createElement("div", "dhThumbImage dhRounded");
thinner.appendChild(thumb);
```

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far to uncover the problem? Would you post a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Are you even appending the element to the DOM tree? are you setting the `src` attribute? Some more info & code is needed here. Do set up a fiddle. _"This code doesn't seem to work"_ is rather vague, what _do_ you see and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: img is draggable by default, try to grab any image here and move.

Comment: onmouseover works fine but the drag functions do not even fire. Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I use these in the public domain library I am building that is intended for use with the closure compiler.

```
/** drag(node n, property p)
 *  sets dataTransfer text to value of property p when node n is dragged
**/
function drag(n,p){n['draggable']=1
    n['ondragstart']=function(a){a.dataTransfer.setData("Text",a.target?a.target[p]:a.srcElement[p])}}

/** drop(node n, function f)
 *  sets a drop event handler for node n that uses function f as its handler
 *  function f will be passed: the target node and the dataTransfer "Text" value
ex. var f=function(t,s){t.style.backgroundColor=s} //sets background the Text value
 *  * the "Text" is set to the value of property p in the drag event
 *  see drag(node n, property p)
**/
function drop(n,f){n['ondragover']=F
    n['ondrop']=function(a){f(n,a.dataTransfer.getData("Text"))
    return!!0}}
```